# How to trigger dhcp4-change using nmcli?

Tags: networkmanager, dhcp, nmcli

I am working on a networking script which will do certain things, e.g., interface up/down/dhcp4-change events happen. 
I also need to generate these events through Network manager, not through dhclient.

How do I ask nmcli to release & request IP using DHCP ?

I found the following commands, but they do not seem to generate new DHCP request-replies.

```
>> nmcli con up id <connection name>
>> nmcli con down id <connection name>
```

Comment: preferably without network manager... just learn how to use the `ip` toolset.

Comment: why can't you use dhclient?

Comment: because the host uses Network-manager to control its ports & I dont have control over the host. Can change to managed=false